# fread in R error: mmap'd region has EOF at the end

Tags: r, fread

I use the following:

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00279/SUSY.csv.gz')
```

This is the result (after waiting a while):

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0  879M    0  128k    0     0  68302      0  3:45:04  0:00:01  3:45:03 68876  0  879M    0  880k    0     0   292k      0  0:51:22  0:00:03  0:51:19  293k  0  879M    0 1888k    0     0   493k      0  0:30:23  0:00:03  0:30:20  496k  0  879M    0 2832k    0     0   583k      0  0:25:43  0:00:04  0:25:39  585k  0  879M    0 3872k    0     0   656k      0  0:22:51  0:00:05  0:22:46  770k  0  879M    0 4928k    0     0   709k      0  0:21:08  0:00:06  0:21:02  955k  0  879M    0 5904k    0     0   755k      0  0:19:52  0:00:07  0:19:45 1045k  0  879M    0 6816k    0     0   773k      0  0:19:24  0:00:08  0:19:16  987k  0  879M    0 7904k    0     0   801k      0  0:18:43  0:00:09  0:18:34 1012k  1  879M    1 9040k    0     0   828k      0  0:18:06  0:00:10  0:17:56 1031k  1  879M    1 10.0M    0     0   872k      0  0:17:12  0:00:11  0:17:01 1104k  1  879M    1 11.3M    0     0   905k      0  0:16:34  0:00:12  0:16:22 1140k  1  879M    1 12.8M    0     0   952k      0  0:15:45  0:00:13  0:15:32 1267k  1  879M    1 14.9M    0     0  1026k      0  0:14:37  0:00:14  0:14:23 1468k  1  879M    1 17.4M    0     0  1123k      0  0:13:22  0:00:15  0:13:07 1761k  2  879M    2 20.4M    0     0  1245k      0  0:12:03  0:00:16  0:11:47 2124k  2  879M    2 23.8M    0     0  1369k      0  0:10:57  0:00:17  0:10:40 2560k  3  879M    3 28.6M    0     0  1547k      0  0:09:42  0:00:18  0:09:24 3154k  3  879M    3 32.9M    0     0  1703k      0  0:08:48  0:00:19  0:08:29 3745k  4  879M    4 37.0M    0     0  1822k      0  0:08:14  0:00:20  0:07:54 4102k  4  879M    4 41.4M    0     0  1944k      0  0:07:43  0:00:21  0:07:22 4301k  5  879M    5 46.4M    0     0  2081k      0  0:07:12  0:00:22  0:06:50 4605k  5  879M    5 51.7M    0     0  2216k      0  0:06:46  0:00:23  0:06:23 4790k  6  879M    6 56.7M    0     0  2342k      0  0:06:24  0:00:24  0:06:00 4872k  7  879M    7 61.7M    0     0  2449k      0  0:06:07  0:00:25  0:05:42 5058k  7  879M    7 66.9M    0     0  2557k      0  0:05:52  0:00:26  0:05:26 5226k  8  879M    8 72.4M    0     0  2663k      0  0:05:38  0:00:27  0:05:11 5313k  8  879M    8 77.6M    0     0  2758k      0  0:05:26  0:00:28  0:04:58 5380k  9  879M    9 82.7M    0     0  2841k      0  0:05:17  0:00:29  0:04:48 5320k 10  879M   10 88.0M    0     0  2924k      0  0:05:07  0:00:30  0:04:37 5381k 10  879M   10 93.5M    0     0  3009k      0  0:04:59  0:00:31  0:04:28 5421k 11  879M   11 99.1M    0     0  3092k      0  0:04:51  0:00:32  0:04:19 5498k 11  879M   11  104M    0     0  3170k      0  0:04:44  0:00:33  0:04:11 5541k 12  879M   12  110M    0     0  3254k      0  0:04:36  0:00:34  0:04:02 5712k 13  879M   13  117M    0     0  3350k      0  0:04:28  0:00:35  0:03:53 5968k 14  879M   14  124M    0     0  3454k      0  0:04:20  0:00:36  0:03:44 6302k 14  879M   14  131M    0     0  3564k      0  0:04:12  0:00:37  0:03:35 6669k 15  879M   15  140M    0     0  3693k      0  0:04:03  0:00:38  0:03:25 7240k 16  879M   16  149M    0     0  3844k      0  0:03:54  0:00:39  0:03:15 7958k 18  879M   18  159M    0     0  3995k      0  0:03:45  0:00:40  0:03:05 8628k 18  879M   18  160M    0     0  3884k      0  0:03:51  0:00:42  0:03:09 6832k 18  879M   18  160M    0     0  3831k      0  0:03:55  0:00:42  0:03:13 5847k 18  879M   18  160M    0     0  3749k      0  0:04:00  0:00:43  0:03:17 4178k 18  879M   18  160M    0     0  3667k      0  0:04:05  0:00:44  0:03:21 2276k 18  879M   18  160M    0     0  3582k      0  0:04:11  0:00:45  0:03:26  304k 18  879M   18  162M    0     0  3545k      0  0:04:14  0:00:46  0:03:28  462k 18  879M   18  163M    0     0  3493k      0  0:04:17  0:00:47  0:03:30  608k 18  879M   18  164M    0     0  3443k      0  0:04:21  0:00:48  0:03:33  784k 18  879M   18  165M    0     0  3398k      0  0:04:25  0:00:49  0:03:36 1016k 18  879M   18  167M    0     0  3365k      0  0:04:27  0:00:50  0:03:37 1312k 19  879M   19  168M    0     0  3323k      0  0:04:31  0:00:51  0:03:40 1242k 19  879M   19  169M    0     0  3284k      0  0:04:34  0:00:52  0:03:42 1293k 19  879M   19  170M    0     0  3246k      0  0:04:37  0:00:53  0:03:44 1328k 19  879M   19  172M    0     0  3211k      0  0:04:40  0:00:54  0:03:46 1350k 19  879M   19  173M    0     0  3184k      0  0:04:42  0:00:55  0:03:47 1342k 19  879M   19  175M    0     0  3152k      0  0:04:45  0:00:56  0:03:49 1395k 20  879M   20  176M    0     0  3125k      0  0:04:48  0:00:57  0:03:51 1458k 20  879M   20  178M    0     0  3104k      0  0:04:50  0:00:58  0:03:52 1576k 20  879M   20  180M    0     0  3094k      0  0:04:51  0:00:59  0:03:52 1774k 20  879M   20  183M    0     0  3084k      0  0:04:52  0:01:00  0:03:52 1964k 21  879M   21  186M    0     0  3085k      0  0:04:51  0:01:01  0:03:50 2325k 21  879M   21  190M    0     0  3100k      0  0:04:50  0:01:02  0:03:48 2801k 22  879M   22  195M    0     0  3128k      0  0:04:47  0:01:03  0:03:44 3424k 22  879M   22  200M    0     0  3156k      0  0:04:45  0:01:04  0:03:41 3883k 23  879M   23  205M    0     0  3193k      0  0:04:42  0:01:05  0:03:37 4515k 23  879M   23  210M    0     0  3227k      0  0:04:39  0:01:06  0:03:33 4993k 24  879M   24  215M    0     0  3259k      0  0:04:36  0:01:07  0:03:29 5307k 25  879M   25  221M    0     0  3296k      0  0:04:33  0:01:08  0:03:25 5442k 25  879M   25  227M    0     0  3337k      0  0:04:29  0:01:09  0:03:20 5738k 26  879M   26  233M    0     0  3383k      0  0:04:26  0:01:10  0:03:16 5900k 27  879M   27  240M    0     0  3424k      0  0:04:23  0:01:11  0:03:12 6047k 27  879M   27  246M    0     0  3462k      0  0:04:20  0:01:12  0:03:08 6208k 28  879M   28  252M    0     0  3501k      0  0:04:17  0:01:13  0:03:04 6322k 29  879M   29  258M    0     0  3543k      0  0:04:14  0:01:14  0:03:00 6389k 30  879M   30  265M    0     0  3581k      0  0:04:11  0:01:15  0:02:56 6376k 30  879M   30  271M    0     0  3616k      0  0:04:09  0:01:16  0:02:53 6384k 31  879M   31  277M    0     0  3653k      0  0:04:06  0:01:17  0:02:49 6439k 32  879M   32  284M    0     0  3693k      0  0:04:03  0:01:18  0:02:45 6522k 33  879M   33  290M    0     0  3732k      0  0:04:01  0:01:19  0:02:42 6582k 33  879M   33  297M    0     0  3771k      0  0:03:58  0:01:20  0:02:38 6666k 34  879M   34  305M    0     0  3817k      0  0:03:55  0:01:21  0:02:34 6891k 35  879M   35  312M    0     0  3867k      0  0:03:52  0:01:22  0:02:30 7191k 36  879M   36  319M    0     0  3906k      0  0:03:50  0:01:23  0:02:27 7266k 37  879M   37  325M    0     0  3932k      0  0:03:49  0:01:24  0:02:25 7134k 37  879M   37  330M    0     0  3945k      0  0:03:48  0:01:25  0:02:23 6742k 38  879M   38  335M    0     0  3959k      0  0:03:47  0:01:26  0:02:21 6291k 38  879M   38  340M    0     0  3974k      0  0:03:46  0:01:27  0:02:19 5750k 39  879M   39  346M    0     0  3993k      0  0:03:45  0:01:28  0:02:17 5450k 40  879M   40  351M    0     0  4012k      0  0:03:44  0:01:29  0:02:15 5368k 40  879M   40  357M    0     0  4030k      0  0:03:43  0:01:30  0:02:13 5488k 41  879M   41  361M    0     0  4032k      0  0:03:43  0:01:31  0:02:12 5301k 41  879M   41  364M    0     0  4022k      0  0:03:43  0:01:32  0:02:11 4853k 41  879M   41  367M    0     0  4006k      0  0:03:44  0:01:33  0:02:11 4237k 42  879M   42  369M    0     0  3992k      0  0:03:45  0:01:34  0:02:11 3635k 42  879M   42  371M    0     0  3970k      0  0:03:46  0:01:35  0:02:11 2887k 42  879M   42  373M    0     0  3950k      0  0:03:48  0:01:36  0:02:12 2442k 42  879M   42  375M    0     0  3930k      0  0:03:49  0:01:37  0:02:12 2233k 42  879M   42  377M    0     0  3911k      0  0:03:50  0:01:38  0:02:12 2134k 43  879M   43  379M    0     0  3893k      0  0:03:51  0:01:39  0:02:12 2009k 43  879M   43  381M    0     0  3875k      0  0:03:52  0:01:40  0:02:12 2051k 43  879M   43  383M    0     0  3858k      0  0:03:53  0:01:41  0:02:12 2073k 43  879M   43  385M    0     0  3840k      0  0:03:54  0:01:42  0:02:12 2086k 44  879M   44  387M    0     0  3825k      0  0:03:55  0:01:43  0:02:12 2118k 44  879M   44  390M    0     0  3811k      0  0:03:56  0:01:44  0:02:12 2172k 44  879M   44  392M    0     0  3799k      0  0:03:57  0:01:45  0:02:12 2272k 44  879M   44  395M    0     0  3790k      0  0:03:57  0:01:46  0:02:11 2413k 45  879M   45  398M    0     0  3785k      0  0:03:57  0:01:47  0:02:10 2647k 45  879M   45  402M    0     0  3786k      0  0:03:57  0:01:48  0:02:09 2971k 46  879M   46  406M    0     0  3792k      0  0:03:57  0:01:49  0:02:08 3394k 46  879M   46  411M    0     0  3805k      0  0:03:56  0:01:50  0:02:06 3933k 47  879M   47  417M    0     0  3827k      0  0:03:55  0:01:51  0:02:04 4610k 48  879M   48  425M    0     0  3859k      0  0:03:53  0:01:52  0:02:01 5447k 49  879M   49  433M    0     0  3903k      0  0:03:50  0:01:53  0:01:57 6454k 50  879M   50  443M    0     0  3958k      0  0:03:47  0:01:54  0:01:53 7603k 50  879M   50  444M    0     0  3928k      0  0:03:49  0:01:55  0:01:54 6608k 50  879M   50  446M    0     0  3909k      0  0:03:50  0:01:56  0:01:54 5701k 50  879M   50  446M    0     0  3871k      0  0:03:52  0:01:58  0:01:54 4135k 50  879M   50  446M    0     0  3850k      0  0:03:53  0:01:58  0:01:55 2646k 50  879M   50  447M    0     0  3796k      0  0:03:57  0:02:00  0:01:57  623k 50  879M   50  447M    0     0  3768k      0  0:03:58  0:02:01  0:01:57  512k 50  879M   50  447M    0     0  3756k      0  0:03:59  0:02:01  0:01:58  208k 51  879M   51  449M    0     0  3744k      0  0:04:00  0:02:02  0:01:58  524k 51  879M   51  449M    0     0  3718k      0  0:04:02  0:02:03  0:01:59  606k 51  879M   51  450M    0     0  3693k      0  0:04:03  0:02:04  0:01:59  760k 51  879M   51  451M    0     0  3669k      0  0:04:05  0:02:05  0:02:00  934k 51  879M   51  452M    0     0  3651k      0  0:04:06  0:02:06  0:02:00 1009k 51  879M   51  453M    0     0  3629k      0  0:04:08  0:02:07  0:02:01  805k 51  879M   51  454M    0     0  3607k      0  0:04:09  0:02:08  0:02:01  872k 51  879M   51  455M    0     0  3586k      0  0:04:11  0:02:09  0:02:02  917k 51  879M   51  456M    0     0  3569k      0  0:04:12  0:02:10  0:02:02  959k 51  879M   51  456M    0     0  3548k      0  0:04:13  0:02:11  0:02:02  949k 52  879M   52  457M    0     0  3529k      0  0:04:15  0:02:12  0:02:03  981k 52  879M   52  459M    0     0  3511k      0  0:04:16  0:02:13  0:02:03 1044k 52  879M   52  460M    0     0  3495k      0  0:04:17  0:02:14  0:02:03 1159k 52  879M   52  462M    0     0  3485k      0  0:04:18  0:02:15  0:02:03 1278k 52  879M   52  464M    0     0  3475k      0  0:04:19  0:02:16  0:02:03 1551k 53  879M   53  466M    0     0  3467k      0  0:04:19  0:02:17  0:02:02 1831k 53  879M   53  469M    0     0  3460k      0  0:04:20  0:02:18  0:02:02 2067k 53  879M   53  471M    0     0  3452k      0  0:04:20  0:02:19  0:02:01 2245k 53  879M   53  473M    0     0  3446k      0  0:04:21  0:02:20  0:02:01 2389k 54  879M   54  476M    0     0  3441k      0  0:04:21  0:02:21  0:02:00 2513k 54  879M   54  479M    0     0  3436k      0  0:04:22  0:02:22  0:02:00 2599k 54  879M   54  482M    0     0  3434k      0  0:04:22  0:02:23  0:01:59 2703k 55  879M   55  485M    0     0  3429k      0  0:04:22  0:02:24  0:01:58 2788k 55  879M   55  487M    0     0  3425k      0  0:04:22  0:02:25  0:01:57 2850k 55  879M   55  490M    0     0  3421k      0  0:04:23  0:02:26  0:01:57 2873k 56  879M   56  493M    0     0  3419k      0  0:04:23  0:02:27  0:01:56 2909k 56  879M   56  496M    0     0  3415k      0  0:04:23  0:02:28  0:01:55 2880k 56  879M   56  499M    0     0  3414k      0  0:04:23  0:02:29  0:01:54 2965k 57  879M   57  503M    0     0  3413k      0  0:04:23  0:02:30  0:01:53 3070k 57  879M   57  506M    0     0  3416k      0  0:04:23  0:02:31  0:01:52 3259k 58  879M   58  510M    0     0  3419k      0  0:04:23  0:02:32  0:01:51 3421k 58  879M   58  514M    0     0  3427k      0  0:04:22  0:02:33  0:01:49 3767k 59  879M   59  520M    0     0  3439k      0  0:04:21  0:02:34  0:01:47 4204k 59  879M   59  526M    0     0  3457k      0  0:04:20  0:02:35  0:01:45 4790k 60  879M   60  531M    0     0  3470k      0  0:04:19  0:02:36  0:01:43 5099k 61  879M   61  536M    0     0  3482k      0  0:04:18  0:02:37  0:01:41 5397k 61  879M   61  542M    0     0  3498k      0  0:04:17  0:02:38  0:01:39 5673k 62  879M   62  548M    0     0  3515k      0  0:04:16  0:02:39  0:01:37 5895k 63  879M   63  554M    0     0  3533k      0  0:04:14  0:02:40  0:01:34 5900k 63  879M   63  561M    0     0  3552k      0  0:04:13  0:02:41  0:01:32 6134k 64  879M   64  568M    0     0  3573k      0  0:04:12  0:02:42  0:01:30 6448k 65  879M   65  574M    0     0  3593k      0  0:04:10  0:02:43  0:01:27 6632k 66  879M   66  581M    0     0  3612k      0  0:04:09  0:02:44  0:01:25 6717k 66  879M   66  588M    0     0  3632k      0  0:04:07  0:02:45  0:01:22 6820k 67  879M   67  595M    0     0  3652k      0  0:04:06  0:02:46  0:01:20 6894k 68  879M   68  601M    0     0  3671k      0  0:04:05  0:02:47  0:01:18 6878k 69  879M   69  608M    0     0  3690k      0  0:04:04  0:02:48  0:01:16 6884k 69  879M   69  615M    0     0  3710k      0  0:04:02  0:02:49  0:01:13 6923k 70  879M   70  622M    0     0  3731k      0  0:04:01  0:02:50  0:01:11 7001k 71  879M   71  629M    0     0  3752k      0  0:04:00  0:02:51  0:01:09 7079k 72  879M   72  637M    0     0  3774k      0  0:03:58  0:02:52  0:01:06 7233k 73  879M   73  643M    0     0  3791k      0  0:03:57  0:02:53  0:01:04 7145k 73  879M   73  650M    0     0  3808k      0  0:03:56  0:02:54  0:01:02 7131k 74  879M   74  654M    0     0  3811k      0  0:03:56  0:02:55  0:01:01 6573k 74  879M   74  659M    0     0  3817k      0  0:03:55  0:02:56  0:00:59 6067k 75  879M   75  664M    0     0  3824k      0  0:03:55  0:02:57  0:00:58 5544k 76  879M   76  669M    0     0  3831k      0  0:03:55  0:02:58  0:00:57 5247k 76  879M   76  674M    0     0  3838k      0  0:03:54  0:02:59  0:00:55 4904k 77  879M   77  679M    0     0  3845k      0  0:03:54  0:03:00  0:00:54 5038k 77  879M   77  684M    0     0  3853k      0  0:03:53  0:03:01  0:00:52 5109k 78  879M   78  689M    0     0  3860k      0  0:03:53  0:03:02  0:00:51 5146k 78  879M   78  694M    0     0  3867k      0  0:03:52  0:03:03  0:00:49 5144k 79  879M   79  699M    0     0  3874k      0  0:03:52  0:03:04  0:00:48 5163k 80  879M   80  704M    0     0  3882k      0  0:03:51  0:03:05  0:00:46 5224k 80  879M   80  709M    0     0  3891k      0  0:03:51  0:03:06  0:00:45 5282k 81  879M   81  715M    0     0  3900k      0  0:03:50  0:03:07  0:00:43 5365k 82  879M   82  721M    0     0  3911k      0  0:03:50  0:03:08  0:00:42 5539k 82  879M   82  727M    0     0  3925k      0  0:03:49  0:03:09  0:00:40 5822k 83  879M   83  734M    0     0  3942k      0  0:03:48  0:03:10  0:00:38 6153k 84  879M   84  742M    0     0  3961k      0  0:03:47  0:03:11  0:00:36 6584k 85  879M   85  750M    0     0  3985k      0  0:03:46  0:03:12  0:00:34 7148k 86  879M   86  759M    0     0  4014k      0  0:03:44  0:03:13  0:00:31 7907k 87  879M   87  767M    0     0  4033k      0  0:03:43  0:03:14  0:00:29 8059k 87  879M   87  773M    0     0  4046k      0  0:03:42  0:03:15  0:00:27 8025k 88  879M   88  779M    0     0  4055k      0  0:03:42  0:03:16  0:00:26 7657k 89  879M   89  785M    0     0  4066k      0  0:03:41  0:03:17  0:00:24 7198k 90  879M   90  791M    0     0  4078k      0  0:03:40  0:03:18  0:00:22 6528k 90  879M   90  797M    0     0  4089k      0  0:03:40  0:03:19  0:00:21 6292k 91  879M   91  804M    0     0  4100k      0  0:03:39  0:03:20  0:00:19 6224k 92  879M   92  810M    0     0  4112k      0  0:03:39  0:03:21  0:00:18 6345k 92  879M   92  816M    0     0  4124k      0  0:03:38  0:03:22  0:00:16 6440k 93  879M   93  823M    0     0  4136k      0  0:03:37  0:03:23  0:00:14 6455k 94  879M   94  829M    0     0  4147k      0  0:03:37  0:03:24  0:00:13 6480k 95  879M   95  835M    0     0  4159k      0  0:03:36  0:03:25  0:00:11 6503k 95  879M   95  842M    0     0  4171k      0  0:03:35  0:03:26  0:00:09 6560k 96  879M   96  849M    0     0  4183k      0  0:03:35  0:03:27  0:00:08 6580k 97  879M   97  855M    0     0  4197k      0  0:03:34  0:03:28  0:00:06 6683k 98  879M   98  862M    0     0  4209k      0  0:03:34  0:03:29  0:00:05 6732k 98  879M   98  868M    0     0  4216k      0  0:03:33  0:03:30  0:00:03 6555k 99  879M   99  873M    0     0  4225k      0  0:03:33  0:03:31  0:00:02 6438k100  879M  100  879M    0     0  4235k      0  0:03:32  0:03:32 --:--:-- 6413k
Error in fread("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00279/SUSY.csv.gz") : 
  mmap'd region has EOF at the end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the contents of the file is in CSV or TSV format, but doesn't have a final newline character in the end of the line. In Unix, that's generally the expectation with any text file. Most libraries can handle that, but some don't. I've encountered the same error with `fread` and the missing `\n` in the end was the cause.

Comment: do you know how to fix it?